# Parallax effect with SKCamera

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, 2d, skcameranode

I am making a 2D platform game (like Mario). I move the SKCamera to left and right with 2 buttons (left and right). The x and y coordinates of the 'Mario-spite' is the same a the x and y coordinates of the SKCamera. I move the SKCamera and also the 'Mario-spite' with 2 px. How can I make a parallax effect (with 2 or more background layers/nodes) at the moment I press the left-button or the -right button. I am using SKTilemaps. The answers on Stackoverflow is not what I am looking for.

Comment: do you know how to do the background / paralaxing, and the issue is that you don't know how to string it up to the left / right button?

Comment: Both, I have the parallax working but when I stop pressing the left or right button, than de camera (and Mario-sprite) stops, but the background keep moving.

Comment: This happens when the camera hits a wall or something, then the camera stops but the background keeps moving.

Comment: can you post your relevant code?